# Uncorrelated errors with the regressor in a reduced form VAR

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, vector-autoregression

I have a reduced form VAR

$$\begin{equation}
y_t = c_o + A y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{equation}$$

Where, $y_t \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $A$ is a $2$X$2$ matrix and

$$\begin{equation}
  E(\epsilon_t \epsilon_\tau ')=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    \Omega, & \text{if}\ t=\tau \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} 
$$

$\Omega$ is not necessarily digonal. I have to show that I can use Least squares method. But, for this, I have to show that the errors $\epsilon_t$ are not correlated with the regressor $y_{t-1}$, i.e.

$$E(y_{t-1} \epsilon_t' ) = 0$$

I tried to use the Wald decomposition:

$$y_{t-1} = \mu  + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} A^{i} \epsilon_{t-1 - i} $$
But

$$E[ y_{t-1} \epsilon_t'] = E[\mu \epsilon_t']  + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} A^{i} E[\epsilon_{t-1 - i} \epsilon_t'] =^{i =1} A \Omega$$

With this, I can not reach my goal. Some ideias?

Comment: What does $=^{i=1}$ mean in your last equation?

Comment: It was a mistake. I thought when i = 1, I could equal the indexes so I have $t-1-i = t$. In fact, it is true if $t+1-i = t$. Sorry

Comment: If that is a mistake, could you fix it?

Comment: I can do this? The problem is trivial without this error. What should I do? Delete the question or make an update? Adding a note pointing out the mistake and the response given by the user below may be more interesting. What do you think of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HIL you didn't write it down explicitly, but I'll assume $E(\epsilon_{t}) = 0$.

So, you're basically there already.

In your last equation, the first term is zero because $\mu \times E(\epsilon_{t}) = \mu \times 0 = 0 $.

For the second term,  consider the expectation inside the sum. It's always taking expectations of epsilon_t and epsilon's which have subcripts that are earlier than t. But, by definition, the covariance $\Omega$ is only non-zero when the  time subscripts of the $\epsilon$  are the same. Therefore, the second term is a summation of zero's so it's zero also. So both terms in your last expression are zero. I hope this helped but you did it all.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I forgot to put the hypotheses. This is true, I made a mistake thinking that when it was i = 1, I would have $E[\epsilon_t \epsilon_t']$ , but in fact, this never happens.

Comment: glad it helped.